# NDSolve with piece-wise function and BVP

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, piecewise, control-systems, discontinuity

How to numerically solve a system of differential equation with boundary conditions and piece wise affine functions ?

Consider the following system of differential equations from some optimal control problem:

```
δ = Piecewise[{{0.0105, 0 <= t <= 10}, {0.0413,10 <= t <= 80}, {0.001, 80 <= t}}] ; p=Exp[-δ*0.05*t];    
equadiff = {m'[t] == 0.5 m[t] - (v[t]/(p * δ)^(-1/2)), v'[t] == -0.5v[t]}
```

Running

```
solution = NDSolve[Join[equadiff, {m[0] == 100}, {m[100]==0}], {m[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

I get the following error:

> [image: NDSolve error]

I also get the same error when using the shooting method with initial value on variable `v`

I tried suggestions in this post [on discontinuous data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55986/can-ndsolve-handle-discontinuous-data)

When running

```
solution = NDSolve[Join[equadiff, {m[0] == 100}, {m[100]==0}], {m[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100},Method ->{"PDEDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}]
```

I get the following error

[image]

When running

```
solution = NDSolve[Join[equadiff, {m[0] == 100}, {m[100]==0}], {m[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100},Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

I get the following errors:

[image]
[image]

Using finite elements tries to solve the system but the errors suggest that it encounters problem from divided by 0 or negative roots. I suspect that variable `v` somehow is numerically negative or 0 at some time points (which should be theoretically strictly positive in my problem).

How to solve this system with boundary conditions and piecewise data? I want to solve numerically, not analytically because it is particular case of a more general problem with no analytical solution. What other methods could I try?

Comment: 1. A `)` is missing somewhere in `equadiff`, 2. What's `rt`? Please double check your code. Also, it's better to show us a complete sample reproducing the issue, rather than embed it in the text.

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

(You haven't specified what `parameters` are.)

In this case, [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) gives an analytical solution.

```
DSolve[Join[{m'[t] == 0.5 m[t] - (v[t]/(p*delta)^(-1/2)), v'[t] == -0.5 v[t]}, 
    {m[0] == 100}, {m[100] == 0}], {m[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]//Chop
```

> $$\left\{\left\{m(t)\to 100. e^{-0.5 t},v(t)\to \frac{100. e^{-0.5 t}}{\sqrt{delta\  
>    p}}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks, edited away parameters (not useful here). I want to solve numerically because I want to solve a more general case that is not solvable analytically.

Comment: That solution doesn't appear to satisfy `m[100]==0`.

Comment: @BillWatts Why do you say it doesn't satisfy `m[100]==0`?

Comment: Plug in 100 for `t`.  It's small but not zero.

Comment: @BillWatts That's numerical noise. Either use `Chop` or start with `1/2` instead of `0.5`.

Comment: No, look at the equation.  It is a standard exponential with negative exponent that asymtotically approaches zero at infinity, not 100, even if you use `1/2`.

Comment: If you use `Chop` to decide when `m` goes to zero, you will see that it goes to zero for `t=56` are larger. That's not a very good test.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just add a high enough `WorkingPrecision`:

```
solution = 
 NDSolveValue[
  Rationalize[#, 0] &@{equadiff, m[0] == 100, m[100] == 0}, {m, v}, {t, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, WorkingPrecision -> 48]

ListLinePlot[solution, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I've used an documented syntax of `ListLinePlot` here, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/1871) for more info.

BTW, you can also use `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` instead of `"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False`:

```
solution = 
 NDSolveValue[
  Rationalize[#, 0] &@{equadiff, m[0] == 100, m[100] == 0} // 
   Simplify`PWToUnitStep, {m, v}, {t, 0, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 48]
```